# How does one call `gdk_frame_clock_get_refresh_info` from Python

Tags: python, gtk, gobject-introspection

While trying to use GTK 3 frame clock in a Python 3 script, I discovered that I don't understand how to invoke the equivalent of [`gdk_frame_clock_get_refresh_info()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkFrameClock.html#gdk-frame-clock-get-refresh-info). I have first tried the obvious, to call the `get_refresh_info()` method on the object returned by `get_frame_clock()`:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, GLib as glib

w = gtk.Window()
w.show()
glib.idle_add(lambda: print(w.get_frame_clock().get_refresh_info()))
gtk.main()
```

That fails with:

```
TypeError: Gdk.FrameClock.get_refresh_info() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

The C function indeed takes four arguments, but the last two are pointers to `gint64`. In the Python version the function raises type errors when called with anything except three numbers. When invoked with three numbers, the whole process crashes with a segmentation fault.

Is this a bug in GDK's introspection specs for `gdk_frame_clock_get_refresh_info`? Is there a workaround, or a different way to obtain the refresh interval?

Comment: I believe this is the same problem as the GtkSpinbutton which uses pointers for input/output formatting, leading to seg faults.

Comment: @theGtknerd Isn't this something that should have been taken care of at the level of gobject-introspection?

Comment: It should... Do you have any knowledge of C, Python, and Gtk to push this forward?

Comment: I posted on the [mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/python-hackers-list/2018-March/msg00001.html).

Comment: @theGtknerd I know C and Python, but I don't think this is a C or Python issue. To me it looks like (most likely) a bug in gobject-introspection specs for `gdk_frame_clock_get_refresh_info` or (less likely) a bug in gobject-introspection and/or its Python bindings.

Comment: Could you file the [bug report](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/python-hackers-list/2018-March/msg00002.html) they asked for on the mailing list?

Comment: @theGtknerd Judging by [the followup](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/python-hackers-list/2018-March/msg00005.html), it seems the developers are already on it, thanks! Please remind them of the issues you've found with `GtkSpinButton`, which likely needs a similar change.

Comment: @theGtknerd Thanks for your trouble. Would you like to write an answer explaining that this is a bug in the binding specs, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the gobject-introspection binding specs. A proper bug report has been filed and is being worked on [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gobject-introspection/issues/198).